# Positive Totient function?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

We know that:
$$\phi(n) = n(1- 1/p_1)(1-1/p_2)\ldots(1 - 1/p_k)$$
where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function and $p_i$ are the primes dividing $n$.
Is anything known about the similar function
$$\varphi(n)= n(1+1/p_1)(1+1/p_2)\ldots (1+1/p_k)?$$
I'm just looking reading material and references. Does it have a name?

Comment: This is called a [Dedekind psi function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_psi_function) $\psi(n)=1, 3, 4, 6, 6, 12, 8, 12, 12, 18,\dots$ (OEIS [A001615](https://oeis.org/A001615)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time you have a similar question, you can try to put the few starting values into the search bar on [OEIS.org](https://oeis.org). In this case, you would've found your answer. (Sometimes it is useful to omit the first value due to different conventions, e.g. here the empty product is taken to be $1$.)

---

From wikipedia:

> The [Dedekind psi
> function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_psi_function) is the
> multiplicative function on the positive integers defined by
>
> $$\psi(n)=n \prod_{p \mid n}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right),$$
>
> where the product is taken over all primes $p$ dividing $n$. (By
> convention, $\psi (1)=1$.)

It starts with $\psi(n)=1, 3, 4, 6, 6, 12, 8, 12, 12, 18,\dots$, which is OEIS entry [A001615](https://oeis.org/A001615).

---

The wikipedia article references:

- *Leonard Eugene Dickson "History of the Theory Of Numbers", Vol. 1, p. 123, Chelsea Publishing 1952.*
- *Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik, vol. 83, 1877, p. 288. Cf. H. Weber, Elliptische Functionen, 1901, 244-5; ed. 2, 1008 (Algebra III), 234-5*

Similarly, the [Mathworld article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DedekindFunction.html) references:

- *Cox, D. A. Primes of the Form x2+ny2: Fermat, Class Field Theory and Complex Multiplication. New York: Wiley, p. 228, 1997.*
- *Guy, R. K. Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, 2nd ed. New York: Springer-Verlag, p. 96, 1994.*
- *Sloane, N. J. A. Sequence A001615/M2315 in "The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences."*